# Autocomplete Search not Working in Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5, autocomplete

I have a search field with the same name and id inside my categories page and inside my products page.The autocomplete suggestions seems to work fine , however once I click on requested product inside the search field, it's stays on the same page and not redirecting me to the view.I want my view to show only products. This is my code so far:

**After update**

My routes:

```
<?php

Route::get('products/{id}', 'AutoCompleteController@show');
Route::get('autocomplete', array('as' => 'autocomplete', 'uses' => 'AutoCompleteController@show'));
Route::get('searchajax', array('as' => 'searchajax', 'uses' => 'AutoCompleteController@autoComplete'));
```

My AutoCompleteController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\MainController;
use App\Product;

class AutoCompleteController extends MainController
{
    public function show(Product $product)
    {
        return view('content.products', ['product' => $product]);
    }

    public function autoComplete(Request $request)
    {
        $query = $request->get('term', '');

        $products = Product::where('title', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')->get();

        $data = [];
        foreach ($products as $product) {
            $data[] = array('label' => $product->title, 'value' => $product->id);
        }
        if (count($data)) {
            return $data;
        } else {
            return ['value' => 'No Result Found', 'id' => ''];
        }
    }
}
```

My view in products.blade.php and categories.blade.php for my autocomplete search is the same:

```
@extends('master')
@section('content')
    <link href="http://demo.expertphp.in/css/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <div class="row">
        <form class="navbar-form text-center " form method="GET" action=" ">
            <input id="search_text" placeholder=" Search products" name="search_text" type="text" value=""
                   style="width: 400px; height: 35px; border-radius: 5px ; padding-left: 12px;"><br><br>
            <input class="btn btn-default " type="submit" value="  Search">
        </form>
    </div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            src = "{{ route('searchajax') }}";
            $("#search_text").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: src,
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: {
                            term: request.term
                        },
                        success: function (data) {
                            response(data);
                        }
                    });
                },
                minLength: 3,
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    window.location = '{{ url('shop/{category_url}')}}' + ui.item.id
                } // not sure if this is the correct way , please advise
            });
        });
    </script>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

If you seems the issue with JS conflict, try below code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Added missing ui css too. Let me know the result.

Comment: I have my JS  cdn and My Scc in my Master. I also put it inside my products.blade and categories.blade because otherwise the autocomplete wasn't responding at all (not even the search suggestion).

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems:

- An autocomplete response should include `label` and `value` pairs, you are returning `value` and `id`.  See the [jQuery UI source docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source).
- Your Javascript is missing the `select` event handler, which specifies what happens when one of the suggestions is selected.  So right now clicking one will just fill the clicked value in the input field.  See the [jQueryUI autocomplete select docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select).

Maybe you want to be able to view product ID 1 when you browse to `/products/1`.  First you need to set up a route for that:

```
Route::get('products/{id}', 'AutoCompleteController@index');
```

Then in your controller, first fix the autocomplete response to return the right format:

```
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $data[]=array('label'=>$product->title,'value'=>$product->id);
}
```

Next, still in the controller, update the method for showing your product (BTW this should probably be called `show`, `index` would usually be a list of products:

```
use App\Product;

class AutoCompleteController extends MainController {

    // This assumes you have a Product model
    public function index(Product $product) {
        return view('content.products', ['product' => $product]);
    }
```

And your Javascript:

```
$("#search_text").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: src,
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                term: request.term
            },
            success: function (data) {
                response(data);

            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 3,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        // Your autoComplete response returns the ID in the 'value' field
        window.location = 'http://yoursite.com/products/' + ui.item.value
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for all the explanation,however it does not work.I followed every step . What's happening now is that search suggestions not pop up  , in console I get this error :"Uncaught ReferenceError: src is not defined".

Comment: I also tried putting src="{{ route('products/{id}')}}"; Now I get an error " Route [products/{id}] not defined. "

Comment: Those are my routes : Route::get('shop', 'ShopController@categories');    - route that shows main shop page with categories. Route::get('shop/{category_url}', 'ShopController@products');   - route that shows products related to category.Route::get('shop/{category_url}/{product_url}', 'ShopController@item');  - route that shows specific product page.

Comment: The Javascript I included is only the `autocomplete` part from what you showed above.  You'll still need the `$(document).ready`, and `src` lines.  Why have you removed your `searchajax` route, and where is the route I suggested adding?

Comment: I updated my original code,please look above. It shows me the suggestions , but I got an error after clicking on a product from search field .The error is "Trying to get property of non-object " inside my ShopController . Here is my ShopController code(related to products) https://pastebin.com/cPAub0pN

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake in my original JS - I had `ui.item.id` but that should be `ui.item.value`.  Fixed.  But you now have `{category_url}` in your JS, I don't know what that is and I don't think it will work.  You have changed a lot, if you go back to what you had when you posted the question, and when I wrote the answer, it will work.  Now, I don't know.

Comment: I change it to ui.item.value. Well you told me that my windows location should be 'http://yoursite.com/products/'  but my products sitting under dynamic url which is 'shop/{category_url}' .So how should I include my windows.location . Also in my route I use category url and product url and here we are passing Id, maybe that's why its not working?

Comment: Your original question did not mention a `dynamic url`, so of course my solution did not include it. I showed you a route, controller, and JS that worked. Get it working, then add to it.